# How do I use pattern matching with parametrized traits?

Tags: scala, traits, type-erasure

I have trouble with Scala traits and type erasure. I have this trait:

```
trait Meta[T] {
  def ~=(e: T): Boolean
}
```

Now I want to use pattern matching to check for this case:

```
(m,i) match {
case (x:Meta[T], y: T) if x ~= y => println ("right")
case _ => println ("wrong")}
```

The `T` from `x: Meta[T]` should be the type of `y` or `y` should be a subtype of `T`.
If the types don't match I get an `ClassCastException`. But `x ~= y` should not be executed if the types are not correct. Is there a away around this or do I have to catch the exception and handle it that way?

I made an running example as short as possible:

```
trait Meta[T] {
  type t = T
  def ~=(e: T): Boolean
}

sealed abstract class A 
case class Ide(s: String) extends A
case class MIde(s: String) extends A with Meta[A] {
  def ~=(e: A) = e match {
    case e: Ide => true
    case e: MIde => false
  }
}
sealed abstract class B 
case class Foo(s: String) extends B

object Test {

  def m = MIde("x")
  def i = Ide("i")
  def f = Foo("f")

  def main[T](args: Array[String]) {
    (m, i) match {
      case (x: Meta[T], y: T) if x ~= y => println("right")
      case _ => println("wrong")
    }
    // -> right
    (m, f) match {
      case (x: Meta[T], y: T) if x ~= y => println("right")
      case _ => println("wrong")
    }
    // -> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    // Examples.Foo cannot be cast to Examples.A

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: added alternative at the end.

You are experiencing the limitations of pattern matching when it comes to generic types, due to type erasure.

All is not lost however. We can rely on ClassManifests to implement a generic method to convert your classes to a target type T (and another similar on to convert to Meta[T]):

```
trait Meta[T] { this: T =>
  type t = T
  def metaManifest: ClassManifest[T]
  def ~=(e: T): Boolean
}

abstract sealed class Base {
  def as[T:ClassManifest]: Option[T] = {
    if ( classManifest[T].erasure.isAssignableFrom( this.getClass ) ) Some( this.asInstanceOf[T] )
    else None
  }
  def asMeta[T:ClassManifest]: Option[T with Meta[T]] = {
    this match {
      case meta: Meta[_] if classManifest[T] <:< meta.metaManifest => as[T].asInstanceOf[Option[T with Meta[T]]]
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}
abstract sealed class A extends Base
case class Ide(s: String) extends A
case class MIde(s: String) extends A with Meta[A] {
  val metaManifest = classManifest[A]
  def ~=(e: A) = e match {
    case e: Ide => true
    case e: MIde => false
  }
}
sealed abstract class B extends Base
case class Foo(s: String) extends B
```

Let's test this in the REPL:

```
scala> m.as[A]
res17: Option[A] = Some(MIde(x))
scala> m.asMeta[A]
res18: Option[A with Meta[A]] = Some(MIde(x))
scala> i.as[A]
res19: Option[A] = Some(Ide(i))
scala> i.asMeta[A]
res20: Option[A with Meta[A]] = None
scala> f.as[A]
res21: Option[A] = None
scala> f.asMeta[A]
res22: Option[A with Meta[A]] = None
```

Sounds good. Now we can rewrite our pattern matching from this:

```
(m, i) match {
  case (x: Meta[T], y: T) if x ~= y => println("right")
  case _ => println("wrong")
}
```

to this:

```
(m.asMeta[T], i.as[T]) match {
  case (Some(x), Some(y)) if x ~= y => println("right")
  case _ => println("wrong")
}
```

So your example would now look like this:

```
object Test {

  val m = MIde("x")
  val i = Ide("i")
  val f = Foo("f")

  def test[T:ClassManifest]() {
    (m.asMeta[T], i.as[T]) match {
      case (Some(x), Some(y)) if x ~= y => println("right")
      case _ => println("wrong")
    }
    // -> right
    (m.asMeta[T], f.as[T]) match {
      case (Some(x), Some(y)) if x ~= y => println("right")
      case _ => println("wrong")
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE: if setting explictly `metaManifest` everytime you mix `Meta` is not an option, you can let scala automtically infer it by passing it implictly in `Meta`s constructor. This means that `Meta` must now be a class, and as a consequence `A` and `B` (and all similar types that must appear as `Meta`'s type parameter) must now be traits, as you can't mix 2 classes. So you are basically swapping a restriction for another one. Choose your favorite one.
Here we go:

```
abstract sealed class Meta[T]( implicit val metaManifest: ClassManifest[T] ) { this: T =>
  type t = T
  def ~=(e: T): Boolean
}

trait Base {
  def as[T:ClassManifest]: Option[T] = {
    if ( classManifest[T].erasure.isAssignableFrom( this.getClass ) ) Some( this.asInstanceOf[T] )
    else None
  }
  def asMeta[T:ClassManifest]: Option[T with Meta[T]] = {
    this match {
      case meta: Meta[_] if classManifest[T] != ClassManifest.Nothing && classManifest[T] <:< meta.metaManifest => as[T].asInstanceOf[Option[T with Meta[T]]]
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}

trait A extends Base
case class Ide(s: String) extends A
case class MIde(s: String) extends Meta[A] with A {
  def ~=(e: A) = e match {
    case e: Ide => true
    case e: MIde => false
  }
}
trait B extends Base
case class Foo(s: String) extends B

object Test {
  val m = MIde("x")
  val i = Ide("i")
  val f = Foo("f")

  def test[T:ClassManifest]() {
    (m.asMeta[T], i.as[T]) match {
      case (Some(x), Some(y)) if x ~= y => println("right")
      case _ => println("wrong")
    }
    (m.asMeta[T], f.as[T]) match {
      case (Some(x), Some(y)) if x ~= y => println("right")
      case _ => println("wrong")
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, if neither solution suits you, you could try another one: instead of mixing `Meta[T]` with `T`, just wrap it. `Meta[T]` would then just be wrapper to `T`, and you could even add an implicit conversion from `Meta[T]` to its wrapped value, so that an instance of `Meta[T]` can effectively be used like an instance of `T` almost transparently.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, but unfortunately I still get the ClassCaseException, even with your solution.

Comment: The above code works for me. Can you elaborate on what code exactly is not working? What are you doing differently than in my code snippet?

Comment: I pasted the whole code snippet into the Scala Interpreter, then I run Test.test():

Test.test()

right
java.lang.ClassCastException: Foo cannot be cast to A

Comment: Ah OK. Try Test.test[A] and Test.test[String]. When you don't provide any type parameter scala will infer `Nothing`, which is not very helpful here. In all fairness, my code snippet is faulty as it won't work correctly for T = Nothing (or even T = any supertype of Any and T = AnyRef). I made a fatal mistake here that makes it totally not type safe. So I updated my post to account fix it. Note though that we now have to provide the classManifest for `Meta`'s type parameter explicitly (each time we mix it), which is extremely cumbersome. Changing the design all around might be a good idea.

Comment: Providing the classManifest each time Meta is mixed in is not practicable, because this code will be part of a library and internals as this should not be exposed. How can I get the Type for calling Test.test[TYPE] at run time? Is there a way via classManifest?
I don't really get the Manifest trick as a whole, but I will try to understand it! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your help! For now I use reflection to check if the parameter type of ~= matches the given argument at run time.
When the development has progressed, I will look into your solutions once more and decided which is the most appropriate.